# Toolbar isn't showing overflow when hosted in UserControl

Tags: wpf, toolbar

Hosted in a `Window`, I have a main `UserControl` composed of other `UserControls`.

One of these contains a `ToolBar` with a few `Buttons` on it. I place this at the top of my main `UserControl` by setting it's `Grid.Row` property to `0`. However, when making the `Window` smaller, the `Buttons` just disappear and no overflow is shown. I've messed with the overflow properties a bit but no luck.

Here's the `UserControl` containing the `ToolBar`.

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestProj.Views.ToolBarView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="706"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="319"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ToolBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Button Content="Button1" />
            <Button Content="Button2" />
            <Button Content="Button3" />
            <Button Content="Button4" />
            <Button Content="Button5" />
            <Button Content="Button6" />
        </ToolBar>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here's my main `UserControl` which is hosted inside of a `Window`, and hosts the `ToolBar` `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestProj.MainControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:views="clr-TestProj.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="737.239" d:DesignWidth="1026"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="256*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="256*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="256*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="430*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto">
            </RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="608*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto">
            </RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <views:ToolBarView HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="OnyxToolBar" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And here's an example .gif of me resizing the `Window`, just the top where the `UserControl` containing the `ToolBar` is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your fixed sized columns in your UserControl aka ToolBarView

you can not give to some control (does not matter if it is a ToolBar or not) a fixed size value and expect to have "dynamic size"

in your situation you could do something like this

change this

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="706"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="319"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

to this (for example)

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: Ugh yup that was it. Can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you!